# Writing a Yaml file in Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: yaml, jenkins-pipeline

I have a yaml file which is the start of a Neoload performance test script-as-code;

```
name: TestFile
servers:
- name: myserver
  host: myhost.world.com
  scheme: https
```

I want Jenkins to build the yaml file based on variables from previous steps/pipelines. I have seen writeYaml can do what I want, and it seems fairly easy to use. This is what I have so far;

```
script{
    def map = ['name':'TestFile]
    map.put('name','myserver')
    writeYaml, file: filename, data: map
}
```

The def works fine, but I can't quite get a grasp on the syntax to add the 'servers' section to the map object. With what I have above, I just end up with name: myserver in the file.

I did try;

```
map.put("servers", new String[] {"name","myserver"})
```

But it doesn't compile (unexpected token "name"), I'm assuming because I'm trying to use the wrong language in a scripted pipeline.

I also appreciate that I could just do the equivalent of 'write line' to the file to generate a YAML, but this file gets a lot more complicated further down so I'd prefer to use this object based approach.

Comment: Aren't you missing apostrophe in `def map = ['name':'TestFile]`? Could you try `def map = ['name':'TestFile']` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an existing Groovy Map with a key-value pair of `['name': 'TestFile]`, you can add keys and values to this Map in different syntax.

To generate the YAML that you want, you would need an additional key of `servers` with a one element array (`-` signifies an Array type in YAML). The member element of that array should be another Map with all of your key value pairs.

You would be looking to append `['servers': [['name': 'myserver', 'host': 'myhost.world.com', 'scheme': 'https']]]` to your map. There are three `[]` in that syntax; the first and third signify Map and the second signifies List. `servers` is the key in your first Map, and the value is the List. The List's only element is the map of key value pairs. The three key value pairs constitute the map in that List element.

Given two common syntax for appending key value pairs to a Map, you could do either:

```
map['servers'] = [['name': 'myserver', 'host': 'myhost.world.com', 'scheme': 'https']]
```

or

```
map.servers = [['name': 'myserver', 'host': 'myhost.world.com', 'scheme': 'https']]
```

to achieve the desired result.